# Powershell Invoke-Sqlcmd - return multiple datasets

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I'm looking for suggestions on either returning multiple datasets, or keeping the session open, with `Invoke-SqlCmd`?

I have a series of SQL queries that use temporary tables to generate a few related views of the data that I am sending on (via Excel) to a manager. As we work on what is required from the datasets, I am getting a little tired of cutting and pasting samples into Excel.

I thought to use Powershell to simply send the results to HTML files as output for the manager, however I ran into a couple of problems

1. If I put the final extracts into one SQL file, Powershell appends all of the data into a single result set (sort of a `union` of the tables)
2. If I attempt to build the temporary tables and then extract each query individually, each `Invoke-Sqlcmd` is a seperate session, meaning my Temporary tables get dropped.

I'm looking for suggestions on either returning multiple datasets, or keeping the session open?

```
Invoke-Sqlcmd -InputFile .\GenerateTimecard.sql -Variable $params | Out-Null;

@{
     'Summary' = 'select * from #WeeklyTimeSummary;'
     'ByDay'   = 'select * from #WeeklyTimeDaily order by postdate desc;'
     'ByTask'  = 'select * from #WeeklyTimeEvents order by HoursSpent desc;'
     'Detail'  = 'select * from #WeeklyTimeDetail order by postdate desc;'
}.GetEnumerator() | ForEach-Object { 
Write-Output $_.Name;
    $fname = $_.Name + '.html';
    Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query $_.Value  | ConvertTo-Html | Out-File -Encoding ascii $fname;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The Description section from Get-Help Invoke-Sqlcmd says it supports GO commands so you could try running everything at once.  Personally I'd use the -InputFile parameter and pipe the results to Out-File.

Comment: That would put all of the data into a single result set which then could not be separated into the individual output files. (See item 1 in the OP)

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the ApplicationName parameter for Invoke-SqlCmd, which results in a different SQL connection.
Omitting ApplicationName will result in the temp tables getting removed the second time you call Invoke-SqlCmd.

Something like:

```
Invoke-SqlCmd -ApplicationName CreateTable -Query 'CREATE TABLE ##FooTable (FooKey INT)
Invoke-SqlCmd -ApplicationName SelectTable -Query 'SELECT * FROM ##FooTable'
```